How to Disable Enhanced Measurement Events in Google Analytics for a Subdomain?
I'm currently integrating Google Analytics tracking into my application, and I have a specific question about handling different domains.
Domain 1: Website (e.g., https://mywebsite.com)
I want to track all enhanced measurements created by Google Analytics as well as custom events.
(Sub-)Domain 2: Webapp (e.g., https://app.mywebsite.com)
I only want to track custom-triggered events like sign_up or login.
The problem I'm facing is that I can't seem to disable enhanced measurement events ONLY for the web app. My current configuration looks like this (I'm using react-ga4):
ReactGA.initialize('G-XXXXXXX', { 
  gaOptions: {
    send_page_view: false, // Not working  
    transport_url: 'https://metrics.mywebsite.com', 
  },
  gtagOptions: {
    enhanced_measurement_settings: {
      scrolls: false, // Not working
    },
  },
  gtagUrl: 'https://metrics.mywebsite.com/gtag/js',
});

Is it possible to disable these standard enhanced events via JavaScript? If not, what is the correct method to implement this?

Going by [GA4] Enhanced measurement events I would understand that these configurations are done only via the Google Analytics admin panel.

Make sure you have separate data streams for website vs webapp
In the admin panel go to Data collection and modification
Click Data streams and select your stream by name
Under Enhanced measurement there is a toggle to enable enhanced measurements

Use the cogwheel to disable/enable events individually



